# Merge 2 not equally Data Frame by Multiple Condition

Tags: r, join, inner-join, dplyr

I have 2 Dataframes (Salaries and Pitching). The Salaries (where we found the salary of the players)  have ~ 26'000 entries and the Pitching (where we found the statistics of the players) have ~ 19'000 entries. Obviously, it is quite more complicated to earn data of some specific statistics than just the salary, so this is comprehensible.

Now i want to add a salary column into the Pitching data frame, but just for the ones which matches (same players, same date). I want to code something like

If players name (from salary dataframe) = players name (from pitching data frame)  and year (from salary data frame) = year (from pitching data frame) then insert Salary in pitching data frame, otherwise write N/A

And then in this way, i can remove the rows with N/A’s and have a cleen sheet with the data I want, maybe a bit less observations but a complete one.

I tried something like:

```html
full_join(Salaries,Pitching, by="salary") %>%
  mutate(condition = (Salaries$playerID == Pitching$playerID & Salaries$yearID = Pitching$yearID))
  

CombineDf <- merge(y=Salaries, y=Pitching, by=Pitching$playerID)

joined = cbind(Salaries[match(names(Pitching), Salaries$playerID),], Pitching)

Pitching$Salary <- ifelse(Salaries$playerID >= Pitching$playerID & Salaries$yearID >= Pitching$yearID, Salaries$salary, "N/A")
```

But sadly nothing did work properly. I would be really glad if you help me solve this problem.

Many thanks

Comment: *But sadly nothing did work properly* ... what does this mean? Error? Undesired results?

Comment: hey Parfais thanks for your comment. Yeah i become the error that the length of the 2 df are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run a `?merge` keeping all x rows (i.e., left join) where unmatched y columns are filled with NA:

```
combine_df <- merge(x=Pitching, y=Salaries, by=c("playerID", "yearID"), all.x=TRUE)
```

And since you will remove `NA` *Salary* rows afterwards, run a `merge` with full match between both dataframes (i.e. inner join) with no explicit `all.x` optional argument.

---

Alternatively with [left_join](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) in `dplyr`:

```
combine_df <- left_join(x=Pitching, y=Salaries, by = c("playerID", "yearID"))
```

Same reason above to run `inner_join` for complete match between both sets by id fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Parfait ! C'est Parfait